# How to create and write to a textiowrapper and readlines

Tags: python, encoding, word-wrap, readlines

So I am trying to create a text io wrapper that I can then use readlines() from for a unittest. Here is my attempt, but when I run it the readlines() returns nothing:

```
output = io.BytesIO()
wrapper =  io.TextIOWrapper(
 output,
 encoding='cp1252',
 line_buffering=True,
 )

wrapper.write('Text1')
wrapper.write('Text2')
wrapper.write('Text3')
wrapper.write('Text4')

for line in wrapper.readlines():
    print(line)
```

What do I need to change to get this output:

```
 Text1
 Text2
 Text3
 Text4
```

Comment: Yes the new answer worked. Looks like I was missing the `wrapper.seek(0,0)` call to start the stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about [`TextIOWrapper` class](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) in the `io` module documentation:

> *A buffered text stream over a [`BufferedIOBase` binary stream](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase)*.

**Edit**: use `seek` function:

> ```
> seek(offset[, whence])
> ```
>
> Change the stream position to the given byte offset. `offset` is
>   interpreted relative to the position indicated by `whence`. The default
>   value for `whence` is `SEEK_SET`. Values for `whence` are:
>
> - `SEEK_SET` or 0 – start of the stream (the default); offset should be zero or positive
> - `SEEK_CUR` or 1 – current stream position; offset may be negative
> - `SEEK_END` or 2 – end of the stream; offset is usually negative
>
> Return the new absolute position.
>
> New in version 3.1: The `SEEK_*` constants.
>
> New in version 3.3: Some operating systems could support additional
>   values, like `os.SEEK_HOLE` or `os.SEEK_DATA`. The valid values for a
>   file could depend on it being open in text or binary mode.

Try the following *commented* code snippet:

```
import io, os
output  = io.BytesIO()
wrapper = io.TextIOWrapper(
 output,
 encoding='cp1252',
 # errors=None,         #  defalut
 # newline=None,        #  defalut
 line_buffering=True,
 # write_through=False  #  defalut
 )

wrapper.write('Text1\n')
wrapper.write('Text2\n')
wrapper.write('Text3\n')
# wrapper.flush()                #  If line_buffering is True, flush() is implied
                                 ## when a call to write contains a newline character.

wrapper.seek(0,0)                #  start of the stream
for line in wrapper.readlines():
    print(line)
```

The rest of my original answer:

```
print(output.getvalue())         # for gebugging purposes

print( wrapper.write('Text4\n')) #  for gebugging purposes

# for line in wrapper.read():
for line in output.getvalue().decode('cp1252').split(os.linesep):
    print(line)
```

**Output**:

```
==> D:\test\Python\q44702487.py
b'Text1\r\nText2\r\nText3\r\n'
6
Text1
Text2
Text3
Text4

==>
```

Comment: The problem is that the object of `output.getvalue().decode('cp1252')` does not have have the property `readlines()` and if I do `wrapper.readlines()` nothing is returned. Is there any way to change the object so that you can use readlines()? I don't want to change the functionality of my code to get the unittest to work.